# How to enforce a type when type checking is enabled in Javascript with checkJS?

Tags: javascript, typechecking, checkjs

In VS Code, you can enable type checking for javascript with this jsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": true
    }
}
```

This works, but will give type errors when VS Code can't determine the type. For example:

```
const chatfield = document.querySelector("#chatinput")
console.log(chatfield.value)
```

ERROR:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

In Typescript you would do:

```
const chatfield = document.querySelector("#chatinput") as HTMLInputElement
```

What is the javascript equivalent for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [@type JSDoc reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#type)

```js
/**
 * @type {HTMLInputElement}
 */
const chatfield = document.querySelector("#chatinput");
```

or as an inline [cast](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#casts)

```js
const chatfield = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.querySelector("#chatinput"));
```

Comment: I tried to avoid JSDoc, is it the only solution? Because once you have JSDoc, do you still need `checkJS:true` ?

Comment: You could always use TypeScript